# List<>.Remove() exeption"index was out of range"

Tags: c#, list, multithreading, class

I've got 2 lists: List Customer and List ThreadModified.

When I create a new ThreadModified I also create new Customer, and make a ref of the ThreadModified to Customer.
Inside Customer I use a Method CustomerLeave() in which I try to remove Customer and ThreadModified from their Lists by List<>.Remove(). Code kinda works, but after a couple hundred of Customers I've got "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Arg_ParamName_Name" exception.

Class ThreadModified:

```
public class ThreadModified
{
    public int thread_id;
    public  Thread thread;
}
```

Class Customer:

```
public class Customer
{
    public required Store store;
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    public required ThreadModified thread;
    public int customer_id;
    public int numberOfProducts = rnd.Next(1, 20);
    public bool served = false;
    public bool unsatisfied = false;

    object locker = new();

    int queueLengthTolerance = rnd.Next(5, 15);

    public void CustomerShopping()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProducts; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(1, 3) / MainWindow.timeModifier);
        }
        CustomerGetInLine();
    }

//Some other methods.. //

    public void CustomerLeaves()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (served)
            {
                store.customersThreads.Remove(thread); //Exception here
                store.customers.Remove(this); //Exception here
                store.customersServed++;
                store.customersLeft++;
                store.customersInside--;
            }
            if (unsatisfied)
            {
                store.customersThreads.Remove(thread); //Exception here
                store.customers.Remove(this); //Exception here
                store.customersUnsatisfied++;
                store.customersLeft++;
                store.customersInside--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Creation of a new Customer and ThreadModified:

```
public class Store
{
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    public int store_id;

    public List<ThreadModified> customersThreads;
    public List<ThreadModified> cashiersThreads;
    object locker = new();

    public List<Customer> customers;
    public List<Cashier> cashiers;

    public int maxCustomersInside = 10000;

    int maxCashiers = 5;

    public int customersInside = 0;

    public int customersEntered = 0;
    public int customersLeft = 0;
    public int customersUnsatisfied = 0;
    public int customersServed = 0;

    public void CustomersBehavior(object id_object)
    {
        int id = (int)id_object;
        //Customer customer = customers.Find(cust => cust.customer_id == id);
        Customer customer = customers[^1];
        customer.CustomerShopping();
    }

//Creating a new Customer
    public void NewCustomerEnters()
    {
        customersInside++;
        customersEntered++;
        customersThreads.Add(new ThreadModified() { thread_id = customersEntered ,thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(CustomersBehavior)) { Name = $"Customer id – {customersEntered}" } });
        customers.Add(new Customer() { customer_id = customersEntered, store = this, thread = customersThreads[^1] });
        customersThreads[^1].thread.Start((object)customersEntered);

        Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(5, 50) / MainWindow.timeModifier);


        while (customersThreads.Count < maxCustomersInside && customersLeft < 5000)
        {
            NewCustomerEnters();
        }
    }

    public void ServeCustomers(object id_object)
    {
        int id = (int)id_object;
        Cashier cashier = cashiers.Find(cash => cash.cashier_id == id);
        cashier.ServeQueue();
    }

    public void NewCashiers()
    {
        cashiers.Add(new Cashier() { cashier_id = cashiers.Count + 1 });
    }
}
```

I also tried to use List<>.Find() but after a couple hundred of Customers it returns null.

Should i remove Customers and ThreadModified from Lists somewhere outside Customer class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Comment: What is `store`? `List` is not a threadsafe collection it seems that you have several threads working with it simultaneously - apply additional locking (on `store.customersThreads` and `store.customers` since every customer has it's own lock) or use threadsafe collection. Also provide a [mre].

Comment: `locker` is not static, so every customer has its own lock. Is this what you want?

Comment: Can `served` and `unsatisfied` both be true at the same time? because if the answer is yes, then of course the second call to `Remove` will fail.

Comment: Also, as a side note: You seem to have a serious modeling problem in your code. Why should the Customer class handle store issues? I would suggest moving the `CustomerLeaves` method to whatever class that's handling store

Comment: According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=net-8.0)  `List<T>.Remove<T>(T)` does not throw an exception ... (but of course it may eventually do in a concurrent environemnt without proper synchronization) Where does the `thread` you are trying to remove come from?

Comment: @PeterBruins,welp, I guess it works fine now

Comment: @ZoharPeled customer is unsatisfied if queue is too long

Comment: @derpirscher class Store NewCustomer()

Comment: @PeterBruins Yes, it really helped. Infinitely grateful!

Comment: Note that you would also need to use locks inside the `Store` to ensure everything is safe, and need to use *the same* lock object as the customer. But the need to synchronize between different classes is a sign of underlying problems. A public lock object increase the risk that classes takes different locks in different order, and that will result in a deadlock. You should keep a lock object as private as possible, and hold it for as short a time as possible. Or preferably, use higher level synhronization, like the concurrentCollection-classes.